# How to call new api function in old api function?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo-8

I want to call a function defined in new api from write() function which is in old api.

`def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):`

     `self.compute_amount()`

This is the new api function

`@api.one   @api.depends('tax_id','price_subtotal','od_month','product_uom_qty','price_unit','discount')
    def compute_amount(self):
        sum=0
        for tax in self.tax_id:
            sum=sum+(tax.amount*self.price_subtotal)
        self.od_tax_amount=sum`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call the new api function `self.compute_amount(self)` in old api format.

```
def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None): 
     self.compute_amount(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None)
```